# Hadoop YARN how to determine the number of containers

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I have deployed Hadoop 2.3 as a single node cluster . Since YARN allocates resources as a unit which is termed as a container , how would I know how many containers are running in my single node cluster (by looking at logs, console etc)? .

I could not find any way to determine that , could someone please guide me to see the number or containers that are being utilized and hopefully the total number of JVMs from there ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

If cluster is up and running you can see it on web app of cluster

```
http://<namenode_hostname>:8088/cluster
```

where port number can be configured in **yarn-site** with property following 
**yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address**

The number of containers depends on resource (cpu,memory) availability.

Following document can give better understanding of container size and container numbers. Please refer

[Determine YARN and MapReduce Memory Configuration Settings](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.6.0/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap1-11.html)